# asp.net mvc loading first entries and the others - late

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp.net mvc razor
The page must show a very long list. Phonebook employees - about 500 people.     Page is loading too slowly because of too many entities.
How to load first 50 entries, and later the others 450 entries - by background?
Thank you so much!

Code on page:

```
@model WarehouseSearch.Controllers.PhonesList

@{
    string LastFirstChar = "";
}

<div id="main-content">  

    <div class="container">    

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h2>Phonebook </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="border:1px solid #ddd;background-color:white">

                    <div class="row" style="background-color:rgba(247, 225, 181, 1);margin-bottom:1em;padding:0.5em;">
                        <div class="col-md-7 text-left" style="padding-left: 1em; padding-top: 0.2em; padding-right: 1em; padding-bottom: 0.3em;">
                            <span class="fa fa-user fa-2x blue"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Search" id="search_input" placeholder="search ..." class="search_input" />
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul id="phones" class="interleave">
                        @foreach (WarehouseSearch.GetPeoplePhonesListResult p in Model.allphones)
                        {
    <li style="padding-top:2em;" class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            @if (LastFirstChar != @p.FirstChar)
            {
                <span style="background-color:#41a7e2;color:white;position:relative;left:-4em;font-size:210%;padding:0.3em;" class="text-right"><b>@p.FirstChar</b></span>
                LastFirstChar = p.FirstChar;
            }

            <img style="width: 85%; display: block;" src="@p.BigPhoto" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">

            <a href="@Url.Action("Card", "PeoplePhones", new { p_no = p.p_no })"><h3 class="phone smarttlink" style="margin-bottom:0.1em;margin-top:0;">@p.Family</h3></a>
            <div>@p.FirstMiddleName</div>
            <br />
            <small style="color:#666">@p.Title</small>         
        </div>

        .... some other info about people....
          </li>

                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<script>

    $('#search_input').animate({
        //"width": "100%",
        //"padding": "4px",
        "opacity": 1
    }, 300, function () {
        $(this).focus();
    });




    $(function () {
     $(function () {
            $('#search_input').fastLiveFilter('#phones'
                , {
                      selector: ".phone, .phone2"
                    , callback: function (total) {
                        $('.phone').unhighlight();                      
                        searchTerm = $('#search_input').val();

                        if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
                            $('.phone').highlight(searchTerm);
                        }
                    }
                    , translit : true
                }

                );
        });



    });



</script>
```

in Controller:
:

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            using (WarehouseSearch.sqldbDataContext sqldb = new WarehouseSearch.sqldbDataContext())
            {
                PhonesList pl = new PhonesList();

                pl.allphones = sqldb.GetPeoplePhonesList().ToList<GetPeoplePhonesListResult>(); 
                return View("~/Views/Home/PeoplePhones.cshtml", pl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512149/paging-with-pagedlist-is-it-efficient

Comment: You dont understand me. I dont need paging.The task is to show all on one page, but that page worked quickly

Comment: Ohhhh OK, can you show some of your code?

Comment: @OffirPe'er I edit post and paste code ot this page. It is running slow even if I remove all jquery scripts and leave on the page only the name and phone

Comment: Show the function where it binds the server side data to the html, are you doing it using JavaScript?

Comment: @OffirPe'er   In controller see in post

Comment: I find the answer!  https://www.devtxt.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-infinite-scrolling

Comment: It looks very similar to what I recommended with the partial view :)
Any way try to change the css, it might boost the loading of the page and then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @OffirPe'er thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend you to use an external **CSS** file instead of inline styling.
That way the **CSS** can be cached in the browser and might help you to boost the performance.

Also in a div with a class "row" you have only 12 columns,it should be like this.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-10">
                <h2>Phonebook </h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
                &nbsp;
     </div>
 </div>
```

I would try change this Action to take the first 50

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            using (WarehouseSearch.sqldbDataContext sqldb = new WarehouseSearch.sqldbDataContext())
            {
                PhonesList pl = new PhonesList();

                pl.allphones = sqldb.GetPeoplePhonesList().Take(50).ToList<GetPeoplePhonesListResult>(); 
                return View("~/Views/Home/PeoplePhones.cshtml", pl);
            }
        }
```

And later in the view after it finished to iterate over the top 50 phones
Call to another function from the controller that will retrieve the rest of the phones.

```
@{
  ((HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetLast450();
}
```

And iterate that, probably a partial view will be good here.

Comment: Can you tell what helped exactly?